# Duplicate Audio input from USB

Tags: audio, pi-3b+

I am trying to duplicate my Line In over USB Sound Card.

I have RPi 3 B+ and USB Sound Card with Line In.

Currently I have an application for stream over IP the Line In audio of USB sound card.
Now I want to make a VU meter to observ sound level of input. I tried to use arecord or sox but I am getting source is busy error because my application uses the ALSA audio source.
How can I duplicate it? Maybe create a virtual piped audio in that can alsa recognize ?
Or another approach for it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After days of search I found dsnoop way working:
[Dave answer](https://groups.io/g/svxlink/topic/using_dsnoop_ed_and_dmix_for/16930183?p=,,,20,0,0,0::recentpostdate%2Fsticky,,,20,2,0,16930183)

But it has to be changed according to your device. for me it is "hw:1,0"

Comment: Please accept your own answer with a click on the tick on its left side. Only this will finish the question and it will not pop up again months for months.